# Do "beaches" and "preaches" end with different phonemes?

Tags: grammatical-number, phonemes, third-person

Not being an English native speaker, I'm consulting an online tool that seemed to me most reliable in order to get the phonemic transcription of words, called ["CMU Pronouncing Dictionary"](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?in=&stress=-s).
This tool relies on a database of ARPAbet entries for English words ([Wikipedia for ARPAbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPABET)).

Now, I was checking the phonemic values of morphological "-s" endings for verbs and plurals (to see how much they share in spelling and pronounciation), and I was surprised to see that "beaches" and "preaches" give different phonemes in the dictionary:

- *beaches* = B IY CH **AH** Z
- *preaches* = P R IY CH **IH** Z

In ARPAbet, AH should be /ʌ/, and IH /ɪ/.

Is this accurate? (My dialect of reference is "General American".)
I could have asked the tool maintainers but I could not find a contact address and the project seems to have halted some years ago.

Comment: I should add this other example that I've just found: (1) masses = M AE S AH Z, (2) basses = B AE S IH Z

Comment: A lot of their entries look a bit strange. They have faces="F EY S AH Z" (AH=ʌ, hut vowel) which may be true in some dialects (e.g. Glaswegian) but certainly not all (IH would be more common in the UK). I'd be wary on relying on that, and trust your ears.

Comment: Unfortunately that's just the problem, I don't have true native ears to trust (especially for vowels) when it comes to establishing which phonemes are shared by which words. My interest is General American, which is the dialect I'm most accustomed too, but my acquaintance with it is not enough. Too bad this tool isn't reliable, because the several dictionaries found online (Cambridge, Longman, Merriam-Webster etc) seem to vary greatly in their phonemic rendition of words and that's why I had searched for something else in the first place. Thanks for the confirmation though.

Comment: *beaches, preaches, masses, basses* all IH for me.

Comment: Actually, reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Any_sibilant) on Wikipedia sparked some new doubts, but thank you all for the feedback (I guess I'll need to read some reference material on this, and deeply). /EDIT: And [this Web site](https://tophonetics.com/) too gives different phonemes for the four words.